# Which one of these query is more effective and efficient to fine Max Value from columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, subquery

I want to query data with the condition to only take data that have the max effective date and the max Level only because the data is currently historical.

These are some ways that I found to query that data, but I still think there is a more efficient but effective way to do it. Please put your suggestion below.

Which one of these join queries is more effective?

```
FROM 
  FINAL a
  JOIN
    (
      SELECT
          MAX(EffectiveDate) EffectiveDate,x, y, z, MAX(Level) Level
      FROM
          FINAL
      GROUP BY
          x, y, z
    ) b ON a.x=b.x
          AND a.y=b.y
          AND a.z=b.z
          AND a.EffectiveDate=b.EffectiveDate
          AND a.Level=b.Level
```

Or

```
FROM 
  FINAL a
  JOIN
      (
         SELECT
            MAX(EffectiveDate) EffectiveDate,X, Y, Z,Level
        FROM
            FINAL
        GROUP BY
            X, Y, Z,Level
      ) b ON a.X=b.X
            AND a.Y=b.Y
            AND a.Z=b.Z
            AND a.EffectiveDate=b.EffectiveDate
            AND a.Level=b.Level
  JOIN
      (
        SELECT
            MAX(Level) Level,X, Y, Z
        FROM
            FINAL
        GROUP BY
            X, Y, Z
      ) b1 ON b1.X=b.X
            AND b1.Y=b.Y
            AND b1.Z=b.Z
            AND b1.Level=b.Level
```

Or should I just make some windowed function query like

```
SELECT    
  X,Y,Z,X1
  ,Y2,Y3
  ,Z4,Z5 
  ,MAX(EffectiveDate) OVER(Partition By X,Y,Z) EffectiveDate
  ,MAX(Level) OVER(Partition By X,Y,Z) Level
FROM 
  FINAL
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Inspect the execution plans and find out.

Comment: share query plan for each query then we can take decision which one is better

Comment: You are in a far better position to find this out than we. What indexes are on your table, the size, etc, are all contributing factors and we don't know what any of those are. With a name like `FINAL` I almost wonder if it is actually a CTE (derived from other CTEs).

Comment: Okay, thank you for the feedback.

I'm new to this kind of thing, I've never looked out to the execution plan